# How to select data from 30 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, keyword, smalldatetime

I have query:

```
SELECT name
FROM (
SELECT name FROM 
Hist_answer
WHERE id_city='34324' AND datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM 
Hist_internet
WHERE id_city='34324' AND datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) x
GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

But **DATE_SUB** is a MySQL function and I need function for MsSQL 2008

Tell me please how to select data from 30 days by using MsSQL 2008?

P.S.: Data type of  **datetime** is `smalldatetime`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should be using `DATEADD` is Sql server so if try this simple select you will see the affect

```
Select DATEADD(Month, -1, getdate())
```

Result

```
2013-04-20 14:08:07.177
```

**in your case try this query**

```
SELECT name
FROM (
SELECT name FROM 
Hist_answer
WHERE id_city='34324' AND datetime >= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM 
Hist_internet
WHERE id_city='34324' AND datetime >= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
) x
GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Try Again, Query changed, since you last copied

Answer (score 24):

Try this : Using this you can select date by last 30 days,

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 14):

For those who could not get DATEADD to work, try this instead: ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me and I feel this makes the SQL more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Short version for easy use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TableName] t
WHERE t.[DateColumnName] >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

`DATEADD` and `GETDATE` are available in SQL Server starting with 2008 version.
MSDN documentation: [GETDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).